# Toroidal graphs have chromatic number at most $7$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm trying to prove that if $G$ is a toroidal graphs, then $\chi(G) \leq 7$.

I embedded $K_7$ in the torus and thus there exists a toroidal graph with chromatic number at least $7$, and I showed that $K_8$ isn't toroidal. I'm trying to see if I can combine these two results somehow to prove the statement, but I'm stuck. I tried to think of all $7$ vertex subsets of $G$ as subsets of $K_7$ (and therefore have chromatic number at most $7$, or I think I could even lower this to maybe $6$ unless it is $K_7$ itself but I'm unsure) and then show that no $8$ vertex subset could have chromatic number of $8$. I then wanted to "glue" together these subsets to show that $G$ itself has chromatic number at most $7$.

However, I'm doubtful this approach will work, because it seems too naïve.

Comment: Hint: prove that every toroidal graph has a vertex of degree $\le 6$.

Comment: The solution to this problem can be found on page 7 [here](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/math137b_s2014/math137b_s2014_lecture4.pdf)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hi! I see why this must be the case, otherwise we’d have at least 8 vertices, with at least degree 7 each, i.e., we’d have a graph that contains $K_8$ as a subgraph. However, how/why does having at least one vertex with degree $\leq 6$ guarantee that we can $7$-color the graph? Is there some theorem for this? Thanks!

Comment: @MishaLavrov I just found the Szekeres-Wilf theorem in my textbook.  Thank you so much!